# How to perform fill operation by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

So I am trying to add a column `trip` to the dataframe using a logic. The logic is that if a variable value is 1, it means a trip has started and when the variable value is 0, the trip has ended. Any other variable values that come between this 1 and 0 is not valid as the vehicle is not running. In my actual data, there are more than million rows with dozen or so `device_id`.

Sample Data:

```
dput(structure(list(SampleTime = c("2020-12-03 09:05:50", "2020-12-03 09:05:56", 
"2020-12-03 09:06:01", "2020-12-03 09:06:07", "2020-12-03 09:06:13", 
"2020-12-03 09:06:18", "2020-12-03 09:06:19", "2020-12-03 09:06:24", 
"2020-12-03 09:06:30", "2020-12-03 09:06:36", "2020-12-03 09:06:42", 
"2020-12-03 09:06:47", "2020-12-03 09:06:53", "2020-12-03 09:06:59", 
"2020-12-03 09:07:04", "2020-12-03 09:07:10", "2020-12-03 09:07:16", 
"2020-12-03 09:07:22", "2020-12-03 09:07:27", "2020-12-03 09:07:33", 
"2020-12-03 09:07:39", "2020-12-03 09:07:45", "2020-12-03 09:07:50", 
"2020-12-03 09:07:56", "2020-12-03 09:08:02", "2020-12-03 09:08:07", 
"2020-12-03 09:08:13", "2020-12-03 09:08:19", "2020-12-03 09:08:25", 
"2020-12-03 09:08:30", "2020-12-03 09:08:36", "2020-12-03 09:08:42", 
"2020-12-03 09:08:48", "2020-12-03 09:08:53", "2020-12-03 09:08:59", 
"2020-12-03 09:09:05", "2020-12-03 09:09:10", "2020-12-03 09:09:16", 
"2020-12-03 09:09:22", "2020-12-03 09:09:28"), Value = c(30, 
35, 1, 40, 1, 7.5, 45, 1500, 30, 1000, 9.1, 10.6, 20, 1000, 0, 
35, 1130, 1, 1580, 0, 45, 1, 45, 60, 30, 1000, 25, 0, 12.1, 50, 
11, 11.5, 0, 12, 1, 30, 1600, 25, 2100, 12.1), Variable = c("A", 
"A", "I", "A", "I", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", 
"I", "A", "B", "I", "B", "I", "A", "I", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", 
"I", "C", "A", "C", "C", "I", "C", "I", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"
), device_id = c("BC", "BC", "BC", "BC", "AB", "BC", "BC", "BC", 
"AB", "AB", "AB", "BC", "BC", "BC", "BC", "AB", "AB", "BC", "BC", 
"AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "BC", "BC", "BC", "BC", "BC", "BC", "BC", 
"AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "BC", "BC", "AB", "AB", "AB", "BC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

What I've tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% filter(Variable == 'I') %>% group_by(device_id) %>% 
            mutate(trip = case_when(Value == 1 ~ 'ON', TRUE ~ 'OFF')) %>% ungroup() %>%   
            right_join(df2) %>% arrange(SampleTime) %>% fill(trip, .direction = 'down')
Joining, by = c("SampleTime", "Value", "Variable", "device_id")
# A tibble: 40 x 5
   SampleTime           Value Variable device_id trip 
   <chr>                <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>
 1 2020-12-03 09:05:50   30   A        BC        NA   
 2 2020-12-03 09:05:56   35   A        BC        NA   
 3 2020-12-03 09:06:01    1   I        BC        ON   
 4 2020-12-03 09:06:07   40   A        BC        ON   
 5 2020-12-03 09:06:13    1   I        AB        ON   
 6 2020-12-03 09:06:18    7.5 C        BC        ON   
 7 2020-12-03 09:06:19   45   A        BC        ON   
 8 2020-12-03 09:06:24 1500   B        BC        ON   
 9 2020-12-03 09:06:30   30   A        AB        ON   
10 2020-12-03 09:06:36 1000   B        AB        ON   
11 2020-12-03 09:06:42    9.1 C        AB        ON   
12 2020-12-03 09:06:47   10.6 C        BC        ON   
13 2020-12-03 09:06:53   20   A        BC        ON   
14 2020-12-03 09:06:59 1000   B        BC        ON   
15 2020-12-03 09:07:04    0   I        BC        OFF  
16 2020-12-03 09:07:10   35   A        AB        OFF  
17 2020-12-03 09:07:16 1130   B        AB        OFF  
18 2020-12-03 09:07:22    1   I        BC        ON   
19 2020-12-03 09:07:27 1580   B        BC        ON   
20 2020-12-03 09:07:33    0   I        AB        OFF  
21 2020-12-03 09:07:39   45   A        AB        OFF  
22 2020-12-03 09:07:45    1   I        AB        ON   
23 2020-12-03 09:07:50   45   A        AB        ON   
24 2020-12-03 09:07:56   60   A        BC        ON   
25 2020-12-03 09:08:02   30   A        BC        ON   
26 2020-12-03 09:08:07 1000   B        BC        ON   
27 2020-12-03 09:08:13   25   A        BC        ON   
28 2020-12-03 09:08:19    0   I        BC        OFF  
29 2020-12-03 09:08:25   12.1 C        BC        OFF  
30 2020-12-03 09:08:30   50   A        BC        OFF  
31 2020-12-03 09:08:36   11   C        AB        OFF  
32 2020-12-03 09:08:42   11.5 C        AB        OFF  
33 2020-12-03 09:08:48    0   I        AB        OFF  
34 2020-12-03 09:08:53   12   C        AB        OFF  
35 2020-12-03 09:08:59    1   I        BC        ON   
36 2020-12-03 09:09:05   30   A        BC        ON   
37 2020-12-03 09:09:10 1600   B        AB        ON   
38 2020-12-03 09:09:16   25   A        AB        ON   
39 2020-12-03 09:09:22 2100   B        AB        ON   
40 2020-12-03 09:09:28   12.1 C        BC        ON
```

As can be seen above, at row number 16 and 17, the `trip` value for `device_id` should be `ON`, because AB's trip that started at row 5 is still in progress. Same is the case with AB's trip at row numbers 31 and 32. Could someone please help me in getting the right code.

Comment: Number of 1's and 0's in each `device_id` would always be equal? and why do you have `filter(Variable == 'I')` in your attempt?

Comment: @RonakShah, they need not be, each device_id is a vehicle, two vehicles can turn off and on at different times and different number of times. Even the number of other variables such as 'A', 'B' etc are not equal across device_ids.

Comment: So do you mean value 1 or 0 matters only when `variable == I` otherwise values 1 or 0 doesn't matter?

Comment: @AnilGoyal, yes, Variable I indicates if the vehicle ignition is ON or OFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
df %>% 
  mutate(trip  = case_when(Variable == 'I' & Value == 1 ~ "ON",
                           Variable == 'I' & Value == 0 ~ "OFF",
                           TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  group_by(device_id) %>%  
  fill(trip)
# A tibble: 40 x 5
# Groups:   device_id [2]
   SampleTime           Value Variable device_id trip 
   <chr>                <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>
 1 2020-12-03 09:05:50   30   A        BC        NA   
 2 2020-12-03 09:05:56   35   A        BC        NA   
 3 2020-12-03 09:06:01    1   I        BC        ON   
 4 2020-12-03 09:06:07   40   A        BC        ON   
 5 2020-12-03 09:06:13    1   I        AB        ON   
 6 2020-12-03 09:06:18    7.5 C        BC        ON   
 7 2020-12-03 09:06:19   45   A        BC        ON   
 8 2020-12-03 09:06:24 1500   B        BC        ON   
 9 2020-12-03 09:06:30   30   A        AB        ON   
10 2020-12-03 09:06:36 1000   B        AB        ON   
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Very nice approach.  I wasn't aware of such `fill()` function.  Upvoted.

Comment: Roman, I just had to add arrange(SampleTIme) after mutate. Without which 97% of rows were NAs. May be we need to arrange data before group_by?

Comment: Yes, the data needs to be sorted by time.

Answer (score 2):

Even if I do not fully understand your description. My suggestion is the follwing.

```
library(tidyverse)

res <- df %>% 
  group_by(device_id) %>% 
  arrange(device_id,SampleTime) %>% 
  mutate(trip_pre = cumsum(Value %in% c(0,1))) %>% 
  group_by(trip_pre) %>% 
  mutate(trip = if_else(first(Value == 1), "ON", "OFF")) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Just noticed that you have proposed almost similar answer/approach.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Do this strategy work?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(device_id) %>% arrange(device_id, SampleTime) %>%
  mutate(dummy = ifelse(Value == 1, 1, ifelse(Value == 0, -1, 0)),
         dummy = cumsum(dummy),
         trip = ifelse(dummy == 1, "ON", "OFF")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% arrange(rowid) %>% select(-rowid, -dummy)

# A tibble: 40 x 5
   SampleTime           Value Variable device_id trip 
   <chr>                <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     <chr>
 1 2020-12-03 09:05:50   30   A        BC        OFF  
 2 2020-12-03 09:05:56   35   A        BC        OFF  
 3 2020-12-03 09:06:01    1   I        BC        ON   
 4 2020-12-03 09:06:07   40   A        BC        ON   
 5 2020-12-03 09:06:13    1   I        AB        ON   
 6 2020-12-03 09:06:18    7.5 C        BC        ON   
 7 2020-12-03 09:06:19   45   A        BC        ON   
 8 2020-12-03 09:06:24 1500   B        BC        ON   
 9 2020-12-03 09:06:30   30   A        AB        ON   
10 2020-12-03 09:06:36 1000   B        AB        ON   
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Anil, thanks, one minor issue. I've few other Variable's that have value 1. Because of which the code considers other Variables' 1 and 0 as on and off as well.

Comment: Karthik, can you please explain this with help of an example.  I think you have understood the logic here, +1 for ON, -1 for OFF, 0 for others when cumsum will result in state as you desire.

Comment: Yes Anil, I am finetunnig the code. have +1 your answer.

Comment: Karthik, do you mean `value` can be 0 or 1 when `variable != 'I'` and in such cases these 0 or 1 are to be ignored?

Comment: Karthik! On second thoughts, I feel the answer proposed by Roman serves your purpose except for the underlying assumption that your data is already sorted on `SampleTime` field.

Comment: Yes Anil, in cases where Variable is not I, 0s and 1s need to be ignored.